# While calculating PE ratio of a mutual fund what do I do with negative earnings of a particular stock?

Tags: investing, mutual-funds, price-earnings-ratio

I am reading one of Peter Lynch's book and he recommends some decisions based on the PE of a mutual fund. While trying to calculate the PE of the mutual fund, I came across a member stock with the negative earnings. How do I go about weighting this stock's PE in the total PE of a fund?

Comment: Subtract instead of add?  (That's a naive guess which you probably already thought of.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index publishers such as S&P do indeed subtract losses from the aggregate earnings of the index. Prof. Jeremy Siegel complained years ago in the [WSJ](https://www.wsj.com/articles/SB123552586347065675) that this practice understates the earning power of the aggregate index in bad years.